# Search troubles, origin of setIsProcessed caller?

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch, search, debugging

**Issue 0:**

Plain old catalog search returns no results; I've exhausted all the hints online, caching and attributes, etc, looked at MANY postings here and on Google.  (vanilla install of CE 1.8 with custom data submitted via REST; but even items with no category are allowed to be displayed)

So I finally started putting `Mage::log()` statements everywhere to track it down.

**Issue 1:**

I noticed the query logic checks for `!getIsProcessed()`, and skips the search if it's already been done, which seems reasonable.

But the problem is that `"is_processed" => 1` is in every place I check the query object, and I can't figure out why.

So this seems to be the primary problem: `is_processed is always 1`.  (I realize it's referenced multiple times as a page is rendered, it's set to 1 even on the first time, and YES caching is off)

**Issue 2:**

I had an idea to print a stack trace from setIsProcessed, whenever the value is set to 1, so I could find the culprit.

But I don't see where setIsProcessed is defined?  I followed back through the classes, `Query -> Abstract -> Varien Object,` etc. and don't see where it's defined.  It's mentioned in the comments, and certainly called.

My other idea was to just override it in Query but I never see this message in the logs.  (I didn't bother adding the if 1 and stack logic since it's not called at all)

```
    public function setIsProcessed( $i ) {
            Mage::log( "*** QUERY setIsProcessed called ***" );
            parent::setIsProcessed( $i );
    }
```

Thanks (and yes, I'm somewhat new to PHP and Magento)

Comment: `setIsProcessed($flag)` is actually an alias for `setData('is_processed', $flag)`. Magento uses the magic  function `__call` to call methods that don't actually exist. http://ro1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call I hope that helps a little.

Comment: @Marius thanks!  It's at least a hint, and something new to explore.

Comment: @Marius first I tried overriding __call in CatalogSearch/Model/Query.php and later base Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php to log, and still calling return parent::__call( $method, $args );  But seemed to not find setIsProcessed.  So finally went to lib/Varien/Object.php and added this to the top of __call:         if ( $method == "setIsProcessed" ) {
            Mage::log( "**** Varien OBJECT __call called: method='" . $method . "', args='" . $args . "'" );
        }   BUT I still don't see setIsProcessed being called.  So the question remains: who the heck is calling setIsProcessed(1) ?

Comment: Doing a quick search through the code I found that the method is called in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_SearchController::saveAction`, `Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController::indexAction`, `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::prepare` and `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::prepareResult` and `Mage_XmlConnect_CatalogController::searchAction`.

Comment: @Marius Yup, I found all those.  But you'll notice most of the time they're setting them to 0.  To be safe I'll recheck the 2 places they set it to 1.

Comment: @Marius in two methods that setIsProcessed(1), in Fulltext.php prepareResult and ResultController.php indexAction, I put Mage::log statements at the top as soon as $query is in scope, and print out $query->getIsProcessed(). In both cases it's already set to 1 before the methods have a chance to touch it. I'm really stumped.  THANK YOU for your continued comments.

Comment: I still don't fully understand the is_processed flag in search stack, but one important note: I'd get at least one failed attempt to Magentix if I change the search configuration; System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Search Type (drop down list).  After a failed search attempt it never tries again, even if you restart Apache/Magento, and even if you disable and clear the caches. It seems to remember there was an error and I think this sets the is_processed flag. If you change the config and try another search, you'll get at least one attempt. After failure it won't even try.

Comment: One question that might be stupid, but I need to get it out of the way. Did you rebuild the search index after submitting data via REST?

Comment: @Marius yes, I had been doing that.  Since I've now got search to run (once in a while), I guess this question is partly moot.  Thanks again for your comments.